# Django 1.7 Application URLConfs

Tags: django, django-1.7

I'm adding an application to a Django 1.7 project as described in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/applications/

What I'd like is just to add the application to INSTALLED_APPS but I don't know the best way to automatically include the applications urls. I'd rather not have to also add an include to the project's urls if possible. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no automatic inclusion of URLs, and I hope there will never be. Explicit is always better than implicit.

Honestly, it's just one line.

Comment: Fair enough. I just thought there might be scope for automatic inclusion because if you add it explicitly to INSTALLED_APPS then you really want to use it. However I can see you might want the urls under a different root to avoid clashes.